# How to stop # bringing up Github issues list?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

Can anyone tell me where to change the settings so that hitting # doesn't keep bringing up my list of Github issues when editing code? I'm not wanting to switch off Issue tracking altogether or to switch off all autocomplete, just to stop the # key bringing up the list when I'm editing code!

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Not sure if this question suits SO.

Comment: @aloisdg it seems to be where Microsoft are recommending questions be posted - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new/choose. Under questions it links to here...

Comment: Your question is about GFM not vscode.

Comment: Sorry, what's GFM? As above the issue is when editing code in VS Code I keep getting my Github Issues list showing up - I've added a screenshot if that helps.

Comment: "Github flavor markdown". What type of file are you editing?

Comment: @OneCricketeer It being interepreted as an issue link is a separate issue from it being suggested by VSC, I think.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat maybe OP have an extension doing that?

Comment: @aloisdg Yes, probably? It's a VSC issue, that's what I'm saying.

Comment: Ah OK, thanks @OneCricketeer.  It happens when I'm editing shell scripts or plain text files. Doesn't seem to happen for JSON, XML or Python files.

Comment: @aloisdg The [list of topics you can ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) explicitly includes "software tools commonly used by programmers", and there are 41 thousand questions tagged [tag:visual-studio-code], so you''ll need to be a bit more specific about why you think this one doesn't fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the tips, folks - it got me going down the right route by checking what was happening for different filetypes and double-checking installed extensions.

Eventually I found the following under the GitHub plugin (which I thought was a core feature of VSC)...

> Github Issues: Ignore Completion Trigger Languages that the '#'
> character should not be used to trigger issue completion suggestions.

It had python and makefile already added.  I tried adding `Shell Script` and `plain text` but it didn't seem to make a difference.  However I then found `Github Issues › Issue Completions` and was able to turn it off completely with that. It means it doesn't appear when doing the commit message either, but that's less annoying than the previous behaviour when I was trying to add comments to my shell script and kept getting these popups!